# Why do I get this error while running the compiler?

Tags: operating-system, command

I was able to install i386-elf-g ++ but there is an error running the command:

i386-elf-g ++: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

But I looked at the gcc and g ++ versions:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I have no idea what might be wrong.